# Can somebody actually find out my name on a Stack Exchange community?

Tags: support, real-name

So recently I tried answering back and to somebody's post on SO. However, he replied back to me with my real name, which is not public. I am just wondering, from where did he get the name, since my username is no way telling my complete name, then how did he get the same?

Am I missing out some settings or something here?

Comment: You might want to flag the comment, so that it can be removed as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How did he get the name?

You posted a Plunker link which clearly reveals a name (which I presume is yours).

You might want to remove the comment containing that link.

Comment: Yup, that'd do it.

Comment: @David: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I'm so stupid... :( ... Thanks a ton...

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sure David... I did that... And thanks a lot...

Comment: Wow... M getting to know quite new things about SO.. Thanks to you guys...

Comment: Sorry about that... :P

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, no. Not if you've not included it in your profile.

However, this is the internet and you can find out most things about people if you dig deeply enough.

For example; Did you link to your own blog in an answer at any point? Have you got a linked StackOverflow Careers page? Do you have colleagues who know you use Stackoverflow and could recognise your avatar?

It's more likely a social-engineering issue than a StackOverflow privacy issue I think. The more you post online the more information you're linked to, so the easier it is to find out who you are. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange doesn't expose your real name to any user. Only moderators and developers (the ones with access to the actual database) can see it as far as I know.

It is possible that you have exposed your name by supplying some of the social media fields for example. Have you posted a question or answer of yours through a blog, Facebook or Twitter? Any code / file service you referenced? Did he look over your shoulder when you were at work / school? Did you accidentally use it in one of your posts?

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick reply. Seems like, it was my fault. I had shared a plunk, and that plunk had my name... But, thanks so much.. :)